# Inject errors into already validated form?

Tags: django, django-forms

After my `form.Form` validates the user input values I pass them to a separate (external) process for further processing. This external process can potentially find further errors in the values.

Is there a way to inject these errors into the already validated form so they can be displayed via the usual form error display methods (or are there better alternative approaches)?

One suggestions was to include the external processing in the form validation, which is not ideal because the external process does a lot more than merely validate.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

`Form._errors` can be treated like a standard dictionary. It's considered good form to use the `ErrorList` class, and to append errors to the existing list:

```
from django.forms.utils import ErrorList
errors = form._errors.setdefault("myfield", ErrorList())
errors.append(u"My error here")
```

And if you want to add non-field errors, use `django.forms.forms.NON_FIELD_ERRORS` (defaults to `"__all__"`) instead of `"myfield"`.

Comment: To match what Django's doing, you should insert ErrorList objects.

Comment: This seems a little bit unpleasant, since the name "_errors" suggests it's supposed to be internal to the form class. Is that the standard way to do this in Django? I'm in a similar situation to the OP: I have a form where users provide a new name that must be unique in the database. If there's a collision I'd like to send the form back with an error on it, but I won't know until I actually try to do the database insert. (In theory the validator could check the database, but that smells and is race-prone.)

Comment: @scompt: thanks, fixed. @Weeble: `_errors` is part of the public form API, despite its name; see insin's answer for a docs link.

Comment: This is incredibly non pythonic. How hard was it to implement form.errors['myfield'].append(my_error) or form.add_error('myfield', my_error)? To much room for error (no pun intended) in current implementation.

Comment: Michael is right. A blessed way of adding errors is long overdue.

Comment: Mostly complete. One extra note is that if is_valid() was not called, then you'll need to set form._errors = ErrorDict()

Comment: @Michael - looks like they took your advise...[Django Dev - Form.add_error(field, error)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.add_error)

Comment: And here's a backport, for those not yet on 1.7 https://gist.github.com/litchfield/7f73238f55b7158b6852

Answer (score 136):

For Django 1.7+, you should use `form.add_error()` instead of accessing `form._errors` directly.

Documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.add_error

Answer (score 13):

You can add additional error details to the form's `_errors` attribute directly:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/forms/validation/#described-later
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/forms/validation/#modifying-field-errors

Comment: And apparently in the post 1.6 development version, they are adding an `add_error` function: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.add_error

Comment: And now Django 1.7 has an official add_error function: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.add_error

Answer (score 10):

**Add error to specific field :**

```
form.add_error('fieldName', 'error description')
```

**Add error to non fields **

```
form.add_error(None, 'error description')
#Only pass None instead of field name
```