# DJANGO: Validation error not displaying in form

Tags: django, forms, validation, unique, django-forms

Rather than showing my form errors, I get the error page saying "Exception Value: columns project_id, employee_id are not unique". How can I get my form errors to show instead? (should show something like: project and employee combination already exists in membership")

MODELS:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    projecttype = models.ForeignKey(Projecttype)
    department = models.ForeignKey(Department)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(Employee, through='Membership')
    def __unicode__(self):
       return self.projecttype.name

class Membership(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project)
    department = models.ForeignKey(Department)
    employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee)
    role = models.ManyToManyField(Role, blank=True, null=True)
    class Meta:
        unique_together = (("program", "employee",),)
```

VIEW:

```
def employee_edit(request, employee_id):
    i = get_object_or_404(Employee, pk=employee_id)
    MembershipForm = make_membership_form(i)
    MembershipFormSet = modelformset_factory(Membership, form=MembershipForm)
    f = MembershipFormSet(queryset=Membership.objects.filter(employee=i),)
    if request.method == "POST":
        f = MembershipFormSet(request.POST)
        m = f.save(commit=False)
        for instances in m:
            instances.employee = i
            instances.department = i.department
        if f.is_valid():
            instances.save()
            f.save_m2m()
    return render_to_response('testdb/edit.html', {'item': i, 'formset': f, }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))

def make_membership_form(i):
    class MembershipForm(forms.ModelForm):
        project = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Project.objects.filter(department=i.department))
        class Meta:
            model = Membership
            exclude = ('department', 'employee')
            unique_together = (("project", "employee",),)
    return MembershipForm
```

Answer (score 0):

You can catch exceptions being thrown in the `save` call to the form and [inject a custom error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/188886/inject-errors-into-already-validated-form) into the form before returning it. Something like this (very untested):

```
from django.db import IntegrityException
...
formset = MembershipFormSet(request.POST)
for form in formset:
    try:
        form.save(commit=False)
    catch IntegrityException:
        errors = form._errors.setdefault("field", ErrorList())
        errors.append(u"error")
```

Comment: i think i need to play around with this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects. I will check it out to see if i can get it to work. Thanks~~

Comment: That's model validation, not form validation. The reason you are getting an exception is because you have specified `unique_together` on your model's inner-meta class - it has nothing to do with the form and hence why there is no form error. If you want to introduce a form error you need to manually insert it into the form by catching the exception on saving the instance represented by the `ModelForm`

Comment: @pastylegs, odpogn,  model cleaning should work - those are called before the hits to the DB that cause the error

Comment: @YujiTomita, can you possibly give me an example of using model.cleaning?