# Set django form as erroneous after is_valid()

Tags: django, django-forms

I need to call an API function after validating a form with is_valid(). This API call can still throw exceptions which in turn may kind of invalidate a field in the form.

How can I do that? I'm looking for something like that:

```python
def smstrade(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = SomeForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            try:
                api_call(...)
            except SomeException:
                form["field"].set_valid(False)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is better to override the [clean method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-a-specific-field-attribute) for the field you are interested in and add your logic there. That way, you can output the appropriate error message as well.

Comment: Thing is I, as a developer, would NEVER EVER expect that an validation function would call some API that does something, in this case even cause real world costs since the API sends SMS.

Comment: Actually, the API doesn't send any SMS; you are sending SMS based on your assumption of what `is_valid()` does; which is why its best to control what is considered "valid" for your use case.

Comment: Ah, I thought you meant to run api_call(...) in the validation functions, sorry. I'm already checking the fields as specified in the API documentation, I'm just trying to cover unexpected API errors inside the form. I could however just let the application throw an exception in this case since it is an obvious error a developer should look in to... I think this is basically what you meant, right?

Answer (score 10):

Bit late, but you can invalidate the form and add display the appropriate messages by setting form._errors

```
>>> f.is_valid()
True
>>> f._errors['my_field'] = ['This field caused a problem']
>>> f.is_valid()
False
>>> str(f)
... <ul class="errorlist"><li>This field caused a problem</li></ul>
```

I needed to do this with `FormView.form_valid()` methods and models with unique fields

```
def form_valid(self, form):
  obj = User(**form.cleaned_data)
  try:
    obj.save()
  except IntegrityError:
    form._errors['username'] = ['Sorry, already taken']
    return super(MyView, self).form_invalid(form)

  return super(MyView, self).form_valid(form)
```

Comment: This didn't seem to work for me in Django 1.4...  I had to put the error message in a `django.forms.util.ErrorList` to get it to display properly.

Comment: Per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28058268/258794) you should now use `Form.add_error` rather than injecting errors directly.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you just need a variable to store a valid state outside of the form object.

```
def smstrade(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = SomeForm(request.POST)
        valid = form.is_valid()
        if valid:
            try:
                api_call(...)
            except SomeException:
                valid = False
        if valid: # still valid?
            print "VALID!"
```

But really it seems like you should be putting this in the form itself, so that you only need to call `is_valid()` once. The only complication would be if you needed access to the request object.

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    def clean(self):
        cd = super(MyForm, self).clean()
        try:
           api_call
        except Exception:
           raise forms.ValidationError("API Call failed")
        return cd

# view..
if form.is_valid():
     print "api call success and the rest of the form is valid too."
```

Comment: What I want to do is tell Django "That field is invalid, even if you don't think so!", so Django itself can handle the form errors in the template and so on.

Answer (score 0):

In case you really want to trigger the form validation by calling `is_valid` a second this is the way you can do it (Django 1.4)

```
form = MyForm(data)
form.is_valid()
# ...
form._errors = None
form.is_valid() # trigger second validation
```